# Android Multicast Receiver only reliable with small packets

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, multicast

I'm trying to receive multicast packets on a local network with my android app.  The transmitter operates in two different data modes.

In both modes, data is transmitted every half second.

In one mode, the output packets are approximately 2675 bytes. In this mode I receive 100% of the transmitted packets.

In the other mode, the output packets are approximately 50216 bytes. In this mode, I rarely receive packets (somewhere like 98% packet loss).

With a Linux PC on the same network, I run a python script to receive the multicast, and it receives 100% of the packets in both modes. This implies the issue is local to my android device and not the network.

Can anyone suggest the cause and solution for this problem?  The relevant portion of my code follows:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    new Thread(new MulticastRx()).start();
}

class MulticastRx implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final String multicastLockName = "MY_LOCK";
            WifiManager.MulticastLock multicastLock = null;
            if (wifiManager != null) {
                multicastLock = wifiManager.createMulticastLock(multicastLockName);
                multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
                multicastLock.acquire();
            } else {
                Log.e("TEST", "LOCK FAILED");
            }
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[65536];
            int port = 11000;
            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
            MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(port);
            multicastSocket.joinGroup(group);
            Log.d("TEST", "Staring RX Loop");
            while (multicastLock!=null && multicastLock.isHeld()) {
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                multicastSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                try {
                    multicastSocket.receive(packet);
                    mTimeOutDisplayed = false;
                    String senderIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                    Log.d("TEST", "SENDER:" + senderIP + " -> " +
                            "Multicast:/" + group + ":" + String.valueOf(port) +
                            " [" + String.valueOf(packet.getLength()) + "]"
                    );
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    if (!mTimeOutDisplayed) {
                        Log.w("TEST", "SocketTimeoutExceptions: " + group);
                        mTimeOutDisplayed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.e("TEST", "Lost Lock");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```